# Power BI filter over 2 pages with opposite filter conditions

Tags: filter, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have 2 pages in Power BI with a few filters. Is there a way to display the data on one page that has been filtered, while on the other page the rest of the data is displayed?

So that you can see the filtered data on one side and the data that has not been filtered on the other?

As a little example:
[image: Filter condition on page 1 also filteres the opposite on page 2]

As you can see on the picture I have 1 filter condition on page 1 which shows the required data, and all other data is automaticaly filtered on page 2.

Does anyone of you have an idea how to realize that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this situation with the sync slicer. Clicking on the slicer and specifying which pages you should override. Just follow the numbers.

[image]